# Reynolds number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

For reynolds number $R_e$ = $\frac{\rho vl}{\mu}$

Can anyone please explain what is l ? is it cross-sectional area of the fluid flow?

Im considering a simulation box with a cylinder inside it. So what will be my l in the equation ?

Comment: $l$ shall be the diameter of the cylinder in your case.

Comment: I think you would be better off asking yourself [how to determine the characteristic length scale for a particular system](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/how-to-determine-the-characteristic-length-in-reynolds-number-calculations-in-ge). I mean why is it the diameter in the case of pipe flow instead of the pipe length? If you understand that, determining the length scale becomes easier for many different systems.

Answer (score 1):

The Reynolds number is a dimensionless quantity, formed according to the Buckongham's pi theorem. In your case $l$ is the diameter of the pipe. Reynolds defined it, when tried to figure out the pressure drop across a pipe. 
The way to see this is, by asking asking what are the quantities, that might affect the pressure drop $\frac{\Delta P}{ L}$. These are diameter $D$ (or $l$ in your case), density $\rho$, viscosity $\mu$, flow velocity $V$ and the pipe's length $L$. All these quantities can be represented in terms of fundamental dimensions: length $L$, time $t$ and mass $M$. Say $[\rho]=\frac{M}{L^3}$. Using the parameters one can express 2 dimensionless groups $\Pi_n$. And find the expression for the pressure drop as a function of the form
$$
\Pi_2=f(\Pi_1).
$$
Where :
$$
\Pi_1=\frac{\mu}{D \rho V},
$$

$$
\Pi_2=\frac{\Delta P D }{L \rho V^2},
$$
In this case $\Pi_1=Re^{-1}$.

The rules of dimensionless analysis actually, don't give much freedom what $l$ can be.
You can read more on Buckingham's $\pi$ theorem and why do we have 2 dimensionless groups more here. 
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckinghamsches_%CE%A0-Theorem

Comment: '...don't give much freedom what $l$ can be.' How does BP differentiate between which length scale to chose, diameter or pipe length? It seems to me this requires some critical thinking on behalf of the physicist, not some formalism from BP theory.

Comment: They are both in the expression. You have to think about all the parameters, that might influence the quantity you are looking for.  In $Pi_2$ you can see the diameter $D$ and $L$ pipe length.

Comment: Ok, but if you define both $L$ and $D$ then using BP theory you should get an additional group $\Pi_3=D/L$ (aka a simplex). Now I can define a new group as a combination $\Pi_4=\Pi_1\Pi_3=\mu/L\rho V$ which also is a Reynolds number but defined using the pipe length $L$. That's why i ask how does BP differentiate? It doesn't in my opinion, only the physicist can (like prof Reynolds did in your answer) by arguing which length scale is most important (diameter in this case such that $\Pi_3\ll1$).

Comment: @nluigi no you should not, because the pressure drop is per unit length usually and your dependent variable is $\frac{\Delta P}{L}$, which is included in $\Pi_2$